# SQL Server Database User with Login

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, security

How to setup database users using the @ format (user principal name)

```
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN Domain1\TestUser1
```

works fine, but I am trying:

```
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestUser1@Domain1.com
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use the format `Username@Domain`, you must use `Domain\Username`. Trying to create a login in the style `Username@Domain` will present the error `'TestUser1@Domain1.com' is not a valid Windows NT name. Give the complete name: <domain\username>.`

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that `CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN Domain1\TestUser1` wouldn't work either. `Domain1\TestUser1` needs to be quoted.